# nest: not found Docker ошибка

Tags: docker, nestjs

Недавно начал изучать Docker для NestJS, при запуске docker-compose up выдаёт ошибку nest: not found

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR D:\Backends\jwt\jwt-auth
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY  . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:dev" ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Команда](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) `WORKDIR` переключает текущую директорию внутри контейнера, т.е. там нет диска `D:`.

Попробуйте поменять на `WORKDIR /app` или любую другую папку. Возможно оно не работает т.к. в вашем пути есть спец. символы, например `:`.